# Ubuntu / Xubuntu: Own login prompt virtual console

Tags: xubuntu

I'm actually using Xubuntu 14.04.2. I want to change the login prompt in the virtual console. Is that possible and when yes, how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? The text above the `<hostname> login:` or the `<hostname> login:` itself or the text shown after successful login?

Comment: All of them :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff that is shown before login resides in `/etc/issue`. To change it, you have to edit this file. You can insert the following *issue sequences*:

```
\b   Insert the baudrate of the current line.
\d   Insert the current date.
\s   Insert the system name, the name of the operating system.
\l   Insert the name of the current tty line.
\m   Insert the architecture identifier of the machine, e.g., i686.
\n   Insert the nodename of the machine, also known as the hostname.
\o   Insert the domainname of the machine.
\r   Insert the release number of the kernel, e.g., 2.6.11.12.
\t   Insert the current time.
\u   Insert the number of current users logged in.
\U   Insert the string "1 user" or "<n> users" where <n> is the
    number of current users logged in.
\v   Insert the version of the OS, e.g., the build-date etc.
```

(src: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/logon.html)

The login prompt (`hostname login:`) is hardcoded into `/bin/login`, so to change that, you have to download its source, edit, recompile and replace it. Have fun with that ;)

Whatever is shown after a successful login is either contained in `/etc/motd` or written by programs that run at login, such as the mail notification. Sometimes `/etc/motd` is linked to `/var/run/motd`, a temp file which is lost after reboot. If this holds on your system, either delete the link and create a "real" file:

```
rm /etc/motd && touch /etc/motd
```

and then edit it, or use the file `/etc/motd.tail` instead, but this will be appended to the MotD, not replace it.